# Scala Convert For Loop to Functional Method

Tags: scala, for-loop, functional-programming, apache-spark

I would like to convert the following for loop into a functional Scala method.

```
for (i <- 15 to 25){
  count_table_rdd = count_table_rdd.union(training_data.map(line => (i+"_"+line(i)+"_"+line(0), 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _))
}
```

I have tried look at the foreach method, but I do not want to transform every item, just 15 through 25.

Comment: Scala collections have a `slice(from:Int, to:Int)` method on them, so if you could slice and then `foreach` you could be all set

Comment: Do you really need the value of `i` in your actual use case?  Or just `line(i)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fold.

```
val result = (count_table_rdd /: (15 to 25)){ (c, i) => c.union(...) }
```

If you see that you've got a set of data and you're pushing a value through it doing updates to that value, you should reach for a fold because that's exactly what it does.

Comment: I thought the domino operator is frowned upon now?

Comment: @JustinPihony - Eh, Martin Odersky makes a good case that it very accurately visually represents what's going on.  And `foldLeft` makes you switch the order of arguments in your head between the initial list/parameter and the closure.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `tailrec` too but @rex's method is what you should be following.
It will not compile, specify Type of `your count_table_rdd` and `res` accordingly

tailrec version :

```
@annotation.tailrec
  def f(start: Int = 15, end: Int = 25,res:List[Your_count_table_rdd_Type]=Nil): List[Your_count_table_rdd_Type] = {
    if (start > end) count_table_rdd
    else {
     val temp = res ++ training_data.map(line => (start + "_" + line(start) + "_" + line(0), 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
      f(start + 1, end,temp)
    }
  }

  f()
```

you can specify start and end too.

```
f(30,45)
```

Comment: That's not functional; you're mutating `count_table_rdd`.  Try again?

Answer (score 1):

Taking this from the Spark perspective, it could be better to do this by transforming the trainingDataRDD instead of looping to select given columns.

Something like:

```
trainingData.flatMap(line => (15 to 25).map(i => (i+"_"+line(i)+"_"+line(0), 1)))
        .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

This will be more efficient that joining pieces of an RDD together using `union`.